# Delete border of UIView when app changes size class

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a blue view with a white dashed border. As you can see from the image below, once the app is rotated the view changes its dimensions and the border doesn't adjust to the view's new width and height.

[image]

I need to find a way to

- Know when the view controller changes its size - perhaps using `viewWillTransitionToSize`.
- Delete the previously drawn border, if any.
- Add a new border to the view - in the view's `drawRect` method.

How can I delete the border previously drawn on the view?

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil, completion: {
    _ in
        self.myView.setNeedsDisplay()
    })
}

class RenderView: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        self.addDashedBorder()
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func addDashedBorder() {
        let color = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        let shapeLayer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let frameSize = self.frame.size
        let shapeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)
        shapeLayer.bounds = shapeRect
        shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2, y: frameSize.height/2)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 6
        shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [6,3]
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shapeRect, cornerRadius: 5).CGPath
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

[Download sample project here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h9pvp7njxeoarf/TestBorders.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Instead of asking people to download your project, find the relevant code, and offer a solution, you should update your question with just the relevant portions of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right way to do things.  Each time your `RenderView` is redrawn, its `drawRect` method will be called, and `addDashedBorder` will *add a new layer* to your view.

`drawRect` is for drawing inside of your view using CoreGraphics or UIKit, not CoreAnimation. Inside that method, you should just draw, nothing else. If you want to use it a layer, `layoutSubviews` is a better place to add it, and to update it to match the view.

Here are two ways to solve your problem. Both update the border correctly, and animate the border smoothly when the device is rotated.

**Alternative 1:** Just draw the border in `drawRect`, rather than using a separate shape layer. Also, set your view's `contentMode` so it automatically redraws when its size changes.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.myView.contentMode = .Redraw
    }
}

class RenderView: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 5)

        path.lineWidth = 6

        let pattern: [CGFloat] = [6.0, 3.0]
        path.setLineDash(pattern, count: 2, phase: 0)

        UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

**Alternative 2:** Continue to use `CAShapeLayer`, but only create a single one, by using a [lazy stored property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID257). Update the layer in an override of `layoutSubviews`, and if necessary, animate it alongside any changes in the view's bounds.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
}

class RenderView: UIView {
    // Create the borderLayer, and add it to our view's layer, on demand, only once.
    lazy var borderLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 6
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [6,3]

        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        return shapeLayer
    }()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // We will update the borderLayer's path to match the view's current bounds.
        let newPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 5).CGPath

        // We may be animating from the old bounds to the new bounds.
        // If so, we want the borderLayer to animate alongside that.
        // (UIView does not do this automatically, since it does not know
        //  anything about our borderLayer; it's at the the CoreAnimation level,
        //  below UIKit.)
        //
        // We want an animation that uses the same properties as the existing
        // animation, but applies to a different value: the borderLayer's path.
        // We'll find the existing animation on the view's bounds.size,
        // and if it exists, add our own animation based on it that will
        // apply the path change.

        if let viewBoundsAnimation = self.layer.animationForKey("bounds.size") {
            let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
            pathAnimation.beginTime = viewBoundsAnimation.beginTime
            pathAnimation.duration = viewBoundsAnimation.duration
            pathAnimation.speed = viewBoundsAnimation.speed
            pathAnimation.timeOffset = viewBoundsAnimation.timeOffset
            pathAnimation.timingFunction = viewBoundsAnimation.timingFunction
            pathAnimation.keyPath = "path"
            pathAnimation.fromValue = borderLayer.path
            pathAnimation.toValue = newPath
            borderLayer.addAnimation(pathAnimation, forKey: "path")
        }

        // Finally, whether we are animating or not, make the border layer show the new path.
        // If we are animating, this will appear when the animation is finished.
        // If we are not animating, this will appear immediately.
        self.borderLayer.path = newPath
    }
}
```

Note that neither of these alternatives require overriding `viewWillTransitionToSize` or `traitCollectionDidChange`. Those are higher-level `UIViewController` concepts, that may get called during device rotation, but won't happen if some other code changes your view's size. It's better to use the simple `UIView`-level `drawRect` or `layoutSubviews` methods, because they will always work.

Answer (score -1):

Call set needs display when the view transitions.You can detect it by using this function.It works perfectly to detect orientation change

```
 override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
self.myView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: This does not fix the fundamental problem with his code.

Comment: It fixes the fundamental problem can you try it @KurtRevis We just have to remove the previous added layer and the rest will take care of itself

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't work. First: If the code to remove the previous added layer is necessary, why didn't you include that in your answer? Second: If I do add that, the border doesn't animate smoothly along with the blue view. Third: this will work when a phone is rotated, but not on an iPad, or if the view's bounds are changed in any other way.

Comment: You can easily call set needs display when you change the frame and if you can read the question carefully you will understand that he is asking for a fix when he rotates the device not on changing frame programmatically as for smoothness if that issue arises i am sure it can fixed